# The title of a song

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> The eleventh day of spring 26
>   The twelfth night of summer 74
>   The first night of autumn 80
>   The second day of winter 86

I have hidden 4 song titles in the sentences above. What are the song titles, and who sings them?

- each line represents 1 song title
- the songs are about something that have similarity with time (daylight, seasons, weeks, etc.)
- the songs are sung by different people
- every song and singer listed first if you google it
- based on Wikipedia
- I am a magician, perhaps by knowing this you can more easily resolve this puzzle.

Comment: Are you looking for 4 song titles, or are the four lines hints for one single song title?

Comment: Does the answer depend on your hemisphere?  Seasons are opposite in the South.

Comment: @oerkelens 4 song titles,

Comment: @Mew no, as I wrote, its based on wikipedia.

Comment: Those aren't sentences...

Comment: I think you need to refine your question. For instance does each line represent one answer? Because according to Wikipedia there are 10 songs of different artists titled 'Winter' and winter is in the text above.

Comment: @Warlord099 the songs title doesn't contain winter nor any other seasons.

Comment: Could you base your question on a source that cannot be so easily adjusted? I can just see the accepted answer being wrong in a week's time due to a harmless wikipedia edit.

Comment: @LordScree I believe wikipedia will not adjust the information I gather, I take 2 wikipedia source to create this riddle, one being the sequence of the season, and the other is sequence of *something*, the songs itself is an old songs.

Comment: Clearly you meant you're an *illusionist*, and the song is "The Final Countdown" by Europe.

Comment: @Raystafarian, nope

Comment: Hi I am new here, want to solve this but cant :( I am Asian and dont know much about English songs. but its great +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am a magician, perhaps by knowing this you can more easily resolve
>   this puzzle.

I assume this puzzle relates to tools used by magician.

> the songs are about something that have similarity with time
>   (daylight, seasons, weeks, etc.)

- My best bet is a playing card
- Playing card have 2 color (similar with day and night)
- Have 4 suits (4 seasons in a year)
- Have a total of 52 cards (the number of weeks in a year)

  ```
  using this fact, and this page sequence
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_card#French_suits
  Hearts Diamonds Clovers Clubs Spades

  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Season
  Winter Spring Summer Autumn

  Now we have:
  Day as Red, Night as Black
  Hearts Diamonds Clovers Clubs Spades AS Winter Spring Summer Autumn

  Search song title at google will bring all song in first result.

  The eleventh day of spring 26 ===> Song "Jack of Diamonds" by Blind Lemon Jefferson, 1926
  The twelfth night of summer 74 ==> Song "Queen of Clubs" by KC & The Sunshine Band, 1974
  The first night of autumn 80 ====> Song "Ace of spades" by Motörhead, 1980
  The second day of winter 86 =====> Song "Two of Hearts" by Stacey Q, 1986
  ```

Comment: Wow.  You and nyongrand seem to know complicated answers to each others questions.  Or maybe you are the same person???

Comment: @Len After he solves my first puzzles, I hope my next puzzle solved by someone other than him, I registered in an Indonesian-language puzzles forum, where I frequently post my puzzles, maybe he was also listed there, or maybe he really is me :)

Comment: @nyongrand You realize sock-puppets are not allowed on SE, right? Sock-puppets are when one person creates multiple accounts to give themselves reputation - if both of these accounts are you, then you should stop doing that.

Comment: no, he (or she) is not me

Comment: @Len Seems suspicious to me too. They've both answered questions by the other one only. Both accounts were created 2 months ago (I don't have an exact time, but still).

Answer (score 0):

For `The first night of autumn 80`, I think it is `Kokomo by John Phillips` because it was released in 1988, after his 1980 conviction for drugs.